# AJAX request in backend template is redirecting to login page

Tags: magento2, redirect, backend, ajax

I am working with Magento2.

I've created some backend controllers, which are accessible in backend.

In my backend template file, I want to call the controller function with jQuery like this:

```
require( [ 'jquery', 'js/Services' ], function ( $, Services )
{
    $( document ).on( 'change', '.entry-edit #sku', function ()
    {
        Services.getProductName( $( "#sku" ).val());
    } );...
```

The implementation of the service method is like this:

```
    Services.getProductName = function (sku)
{
    var request = $.ajax( {
        url: "/admin123/backend/Product/showName?sku=" + sku,
        type: 'GET'
    } );

    request.done( function ( result )
    {
        $( "#name" ).val( result );
    } );

    request.fail( function ( error )
    {
        console.dir(error);
        $( "#name" ).val( "Produkt nicht gefunden" );
    } );

};
```

My backend controller:

```
class ShowName extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    const ADMIN_RESOURCE = 'Ruck_Restclient::showName';

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return true;//$this->_authorization->isAllowed(self::ADMIN_RESOURCE);
}

/**
 * @return void
 */
public function execute()
{
    try
    {
        $sku = $this->getRequest()->getParam( 'sku' );
        $helper = new Data();
        $productName = $helper->getKundenArtikelNumberByProductNumber( $sku );
        $this->getResponse()->setBody( $productName );
    }
    catch ( Exception $ex )
    {
        $this->getResponse()->setBody( $ex->getMessage() );
    }
}
```

}

I'm not able to to proceed the `getProductname()` function. After the call is fired in adminhtml/product/edit/tabs, I'm getting immediatly redirected to backend login page.

After my research, I figured out, that the dispatch method from `\Magento\Backend\App\Action` checks the login status and redirects to login page if status is not logged in.

My expectation is, that if I fire an request from an admintemplate (`adminhtml/product/edit/tabs`) which is inside backend scope, I could consume the controller action.

Do I need to add some additional login headers or is my proceed basically wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento is using [secure key validation](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Backend/App/AbstractAction.php#L247) in admin aria.

Simplest way to use secure key is use **POST** and add form_key to data. Example:

```
jQuery.ajax( {
    url: 'http://mage.dev/admin/vendor/module/validateTest',
    data: {form_key: window.FORM_KEY},
    type: 'POST'
}).done(function(a) { 
    console.log(a); // log: {a: "b"}
});
```

And my controller looks like

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Entity;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;

/**
 * Entity validate
 */
class ValidateTest extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory
     */
    protected $resultJsonFactory;

    /**
     * ValidateTest constructor.
     * @param Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Validate product
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->resultJsonFactory->create()->setData([
            'a' => 'b'
        ]);
    }


   /**
     * Check for is allowed
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Vendor_Module::resource');
    }
}
```

Comment: Well that sux.. I did as instructed and it give http://mydomain/admin/gift/gift/testConroller?isAjax=true 404 (Forbidden)

Comment: this is crazy ... 404 forbidden, not 403

Comment: May be your admin url doesn't have secure key in it. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104069/magento2-how-to-generate-admin-url-with-secure-key-from-a-controller

Comment: You can generate URL with form_key when you rendering your block. Something like: `{requestUrl: <?=json_encode($this->getUrl("...")) ?>}`. It allows you to generate proper URL without hardcoding any values in the template and key will be there automatically, if enabled.

Comment: Everything is working fine but there is warning in console "Expected to start loader but did not find one in the dom", Can you please give any idea about this

Comment: Not working, got ajaxExpired: 1 error in response. and admin session timeout.