# Magento2: How to generate admin url with secure key from a controller

Tags: magento2, url-key, custom-admin-url

I want to know, how can I generate a valid admin url from

1. A Controller
2. Anywhnere

so I can make any custom url admin work if I need it in an ajax or whatever. Answer for either 1 or 2 will do the job, bot I think it is better to have both.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From a controller you can simply use `$this->getUrl('url/path/here', $paramsHere = array())`.

From anywhere else:

You need to add an instance of `\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface` in your class and use that:

```
protected $urlBuider;
public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
    ....
}
```

Then you can use this:

```
$url = $this->urlBuilder->getUrl('url/path/here', $paramsHere = array());
```

Comment: In Magento 2.0.6 getUrl() is defined in \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface not (or no longer or not yet) in \Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface!

Comment: Yep. This has changed. You are right.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate secure admin url key by

```
protected $urlBuider;
public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
    ....
}

public function Yourmethod()
{
$this->urlBuilder->getRouteUrl('RouteId/ControllerName/actionName',[ 'key'=>$this->urlBuilder->getSecretKey('RouteId','ControllerName','actionName')])
}
```

If you want to send parameters then add your params before key

```
$this->urlBuilder->getRouteUrl('RouteId/ControllerName/actionName',[ 'param1'=> 'paramValue1','param2'=> 'paramValue2','key'=>$this->urlBuilder->getSecretKey('RouteId','ControllerName','actionName')])
```