# getAdminLink under Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, controllers

i'm trying to adapt a module from Prestashop to Magento 2 did someone know how i can traslate this pls i need to use it in Magento 2:

```
$this->context->link->getAdminLink(-------)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inject `Magento\Framework\UrlInterface` and call

`$url = $this->urlBuilder->getUrl('url/path/here', $paramsHere = array());`

This is correct way include admin link

**For reference for good Answer :**

[Magento2: How to generate admin url with secure key from a controller](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104069/magento2-how-to-generate-admin-url-with-secure-key-from-a-controller?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: unfortunately i have an error "Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons." i didn't put the function someFunction() yet only the code above

Comment: i will check it

Comment: Just rename local.xml.sample to local.xml within pub/errors directory and check

Comment: i have this error i'm gonna check : Recoverable Error: Argument 2 passed to Mymodule\AdminPage\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index::__construct() must implement interface Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface, instance of Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory given, called in /home/mademonstration/public_html/newmagento3/var/generation/Mymodule/AdminPage/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index/Interceptor.php on line 14 and defined in /home/mademonstration/public_html/newmagento3/app/code/Mymodule/AdminPage/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index.php on line 21

Comment: 10 min i will check and provide code

Comment: do you want my full controller it may help maybe ?

Comment: yes please provide

Answer (score 0):

i found out

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$this->_backendUrl->getUrl('-------');
```